# Работа с общим ресурсом в приложении

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Хотелось бы прояснить, считается ли такая практика работы с объектом настроек правильной. Есть объект внутри приложения, который хранит в памяти все текущие параметры:

```
  public class Settings : ICloneable
    {
    public string Code1{get;private set;}
    public string Code2{get;private set;}

   private Settings _actualSettings;

    public Settings(string code1,string code2)
    {
     Code1 = code1;
     Code2 = code2
    }

    public void UpdateSettings(string code1,string code2)
    {
     Code1 = code1;
     Code2 = code2;
     Commit();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
     _actualSettings =  (Settings) Clone()
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new Settings { Code1 = Code1  , Code2 = Code2  };
    }

    }

    public Settings GetSettings()
    {
     return _actualSettings;
    }
```

Может быть множество параметров настроек, которые меняются абсолютно из разных мест и может быть множество перегрузок метода UpdateSettings (обновляться могут только некоторые параметры)

Настройки запрашиваются в разных местах и нужно, чтобы в один момент времени рабочая версия настроек для всех пользователей была одинаковой.

Является ли такой механизм правильным с архитектурной точки зрения? Если нет - как правильно организовать такое хранилище в памяти?

Comment: Если приложение многопоточной то эффекты могут быть совсем неожиданные.  Если нет то думаю все будет нормально.

Comment: Приложение многопоточное. Каким образом можно контролировать, что в момент времени у всех один и тот же экземпляр настроек?

Comment: на вскидку - либо синглтон, либо статический класс настроек и блокировки на доступ для потокобезопасности, формата: пишет только один, остальные ждут, читают все, пока хоть кто-то читает - запись ждет.